# Knödel numbers - Find Kn

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, number-theory

The Knödel numbers are a set of sequences. Specifically, the Knödel numbers for a positive integer \$n\$ are the set of composite numbers \$m\$, such that all \$i < m\$, [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) to \$m\$, satisfy \$i^{(m-n)} \equiv 1 \mod m\$. The set of Knödel numbers for a specific \$n\$ is denoted \$K_n\$. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kn%C3%B6del_number)).

For example, \$K_1\$ are the [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number), and [OEIS A002997](https://oeis.org/A002997). They go like: \$\{561, 1105, 1729, 2465, 2821, 6601, ... \}\$. \$K_2\$ is [OEIS A050990](https://oeis.org/A050990) and goes like, \$\{4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 22, 24, 26, ... \}\$.

### Your task

Your task is to write a program/function/etc. that takes two numbers, \$n\$ and \$p\$. It should return the first \$p\$ numbers of the Knödel Sequence, \$K_n\$.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

### Examples

```
1, 6   ->   [561, 1105, 1729, 2465, 2821, 6601]
2, 3   ->   [4, 6, 8]
4, 9   ->   [6, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 40, 44]
3, 1   ->   [9]
3, 0   ->   []
21, 21 ->   [45, 57, 63, 85, 105, 117, 147, 231, 273, 357, 399, 441, 483, 585, 609, 651, 741, 777, 861, 903, 987]
```

Comment: Why is `4` not in the sequence `K_4`? `i^(4-4) = 1 mod 4` is always true.

Comment: @isaacg [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KnoedelNumbers.html) has the additional condition that `m > n`.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
.f&tPZ!f&q1iTZt%^T-ZQZSZvzhQ
```

*1 byte saved thanks to Jakube and orlp.*

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.f%26tPZ!f%26q1iTZt%25%5ET-ZQZSZvzhQ&input=5%0A21&debug=0)

Input in the form

```
p
n
```

A fairly straightforward calculation. Relative primeness is checked via Pyth's gcd function. This code showcases `.f`, Pyth's "first n satisfying" function.

I have incorporated the implicit condition that `m > n` by starting the search for `m` values at `n + 1`.

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, 89 bytes

Very straightforward implementation. Defines a binary operator `n!p`.

```
n!p=take p[m|m<-[n+1..],any((<1).mod m)[2..m-1],and[i^(m-n)`mod`m<2|i<-[1..m],gcd i m<2]]
```

Example:

```
Prelude> 4!9
[6,8,12,16,20,24,28,40,44]
```

Comment: What is `m>n` for?

Comment: I have no idea. I was getting `negative exponent` errors on `21!21`, and adding that in solved the problem.

Comment: I installed Haskell to try and figure out how to get rid of the `m>n&&` bit, changing `m<-[4..]` to `m<-[n+1..]` seems to work. You also get a byte count of 91!

Comment: Neat! Thanks, @Vioz.

Comment: @Vioz- So you meddled with Haskell without knowing Haskell before? How did you do it?

Comment: also, a tip - you can use `any` and `all` instead of `or` and `and`. sometimes these are shorter, and sometimes these are shorter.

Comment: @proudhaskeller Well, it's a fairly simple language to understand, so I just began investigating changing different things in the ranges to help fix the issue. I figured since the raising to the negative power was an issue, then obviously m's size was an issue, so I found the range it was defined and figured as long as the range started at a value greater than n the exponent wouldn't be negative

Comment: @Vioz- first time hearing someone saying Haskell is a simple language to understand. I mostly just hear of people who think they don't understand monads or purity or how to do stuff without loops. If Haskell is easy for you, then good luck with learning more of it! (If you want to, of course)

Comment: @proudhaskeller: I thought I'd checked, but turns out `any` is a bit shorter after all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 90

```
a#b=gcd a b>1
n!p=take p[m|m<-[n+1..],any(m#)[2..m-1],all(\i->m#i||mod(i^(m-n))m<2)[1..m]]
```

much the same as @Marius 's answer, though developed independently.